GTM: Trigger fired, but Event failed
I am trying to setup a GA4 Event to track external links to a specific website/page.
I have setup the trigger based on the ClickUrl of the specific website page the visitors will be clicking to.
The trigger seems to be firing fine, but the Event seems to fail in Preview mode. Please see below.


And this is the basic Tag setup:

Can anyone explain why the Event is not successful? I have verified no blocks or 404's via the Network tab in the Dev Tools.
Thanks

Your measure ID needs to be the unique ID associated with your GA4 property. It is like G-XXXXXXXXX. Your event is happening but it doesn't know where to send the data. Fix this and you should see you data.

@A_Patterson- Thank you, that was it.
